# Node.JS scrape encoding?

Tags: node.js, unicode, encoding

I'm fetching [this page](http://www.relaisentrecote.fr/) with with [this request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) in Node.JS, and parsing the body using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio).

Calling `$.html()` on the parsed response body reveals that the title attribute for the page is:

```
<title>Le Relais de l'Entrec?te</title>
```

... when it should be:

```
<title>Le Relais de l'Entrecôte</title>
```

I've tried setting the options for the request library to include `encoding: 'utf8'`, but that didn't seem to change anything.

How do I preserve these characters?

Comment: cheerio might also just exhibit [this bug](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/548), which incorrectly outputs certain characters in certain situations

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The page appears to be encoded with iso-8859-1.  You'll need to tell `request` to hand you back an un-encoded buffer by passing `encoding: null` and use something like [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv) to convert it.

If you're writing a generalized crawler, you'll have to figure out how to detect the encoding of each page you encounter to decode it correctly, otherwise the following should work for your case:

```js
var request = require('request');                                               
var iconv = require('iconv');                                                   

request.get({                                                                   
  url: 'http://www.relaisentrecote.fr',                                         
  encoding: null,                                                               
}, function(err, res, body) {                                                   
  var ic = new iconv.Iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');                              
  var buf = ic.convert(body);                                                   
  var utf8String = buf.toString('utf-8');  
  // .. do something with utf8String ..                                                                             
});
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use [iconv](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv) (or better [iconv-lite](https://npmjs.org/package/iconv-lite)) for the conversion itself, but to detect the encoding you should check out the [charset](https://github.com/fengmk2/charset) and [jschardet](https://github.com/aadsm/jschardet) modules. Here's an example of them both in action:

```
var charset = require('charset'),
    jschardet = require('jschardet'),
    Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;

request.get({url: 'http://www.example.com', encoding: 'binary'}, function(err, res, body) {
    var enc = charset(res.headers, body) || jschardet.detect(body).encoding.toLowerCase();

    if(enc !== 'utf8') {
        var iconv = new Iconv(enc, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE');
        body = iconv.convert(new Buffer(body, 'binary')).toString('utf8');
    }

    console.log(body);
});
```

---

Comment: I think this is a better answer as it takes response header into consideration.

Comment: Yes this is definitely a better answer and should be the accepted one

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It cleverly uses all available means (apart from asking the developer of the site) to detect the encoding and it succeeds!

Comment: Note that jschardet v2.2.1 will return 'UTF-8', which won't match 'utf8' after making it lowercase.